# How to change the values of colors.xml programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to change the color of my drawable/vector file programmatically at runtime, the color code will be coming from API, anyone know how i can change the colors at run time or is there any other way?

Comment: You can't. The apk is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the color of my drawable/vector file programmatically at runtime

You can fill the tint color of your drawable at runtime using this:

```
    newDrawable = yourDrawable.mutate();
    newDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(newDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(newDrawable, intColor);
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(newDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```